# Scrapy - getting the the file size and type from a URL without downloading the file?

Tags: python, header, request, web-scraping, scrapy

In Scrapy I want to crawl some pages that have large .zip files, and retrieve some data (size, url, etc.) about those files. One way I could do this is to yield requests for these urls, but I think this downloads the files. How can I get only the header from the URLs of the zips? Would it be better not to crawl the URL that I want the header from, and instead retrieve it some other way?

Comment: Looks like you want to make HEAD rather than GET requests for those files, but apparently `scrapy` has some problems with that, e.g see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-developers/dMb_i8FJiKo .  So if you can avoid the normal scrapy processing for those specific URLs and shunt them aside to your own code (where you just make a HEAD request and process the resulting headers) that might indeed be best (or, help fix scrapy, perhaps...?-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yield [requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) and specify [`HEAD`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) as a method:

```
yield Request(url, method="HEAD", callback=self.callback)
```

Then, in the callback read the headers from [`response.headers`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.headers):

```
def callback(self, response):
    print response.headers
```